# sitefinity 5: How do I link to another blog post

Tags: blogs, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

In Blog Post A, I'd like to reference a previous post within the same blog. "For more information on this, please see [this other article](http://#)."

Is there a way for me make 'this other article' a link to another existing post within the same blog?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not as easy as you would think.  When you create the link in the "new" blog post you will have to paste in the absolute url of the "old" post into the link creator.

I did hear that in SF6 they will have the ability to select posts like pages.